# How to set global variables in Citrus in pure java?

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I'm wondering how to set up global variables in Citrus in pure Java. In [Citrus documentnation](http://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/html/index.html#global-variables)
there is a sample how to do this in XML but is there any way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these beans to the Spring application context using pure Spring Java configuration like this:

```
@Bean
public GlobalVariables globalVariables() {
    GlobalVariables globalVariables = new GlobalVariables();
    globalVariables.getVariables().put("myVar", "foo");
    return globalVariables;
}
```

If you want to load a properties file and let Citrus convert these to global test variables you can use this bean in addition to the mentioned above.

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("globalVariables")
public GlobalVariablesPropertyLoader globalVariablesPropertyLoader() {
    GlobalVariablesPropertyLoader globalVariablesPropertyLoader = new GlobalVariablesPropertyLoader();
    globalVariablesPropertyLoader.getPropertyFiles().add("classpath:global.properties");
    return globalVariablesPropertyLoader;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Christoph! This is what I'm looking for :-)